# How to detect if a MouseDown is over Row Resize Area

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have subclassed `DataGridView` to implement drag-and-drop of grid rows using `OnMouseDown/Move` to start the drag. It works well but the problem I am facing is that the user can no longer resize the rows. Is there a way to detect in `OnMouseDown` that the pointer is in the "resize row" hot zone so that I can skip starting the drag-and-drop?

Note that `HitTestInfo.Type` does not differentiate between the row header and the row separator. There is an internal field (`typeInternal`) that does, but is not accessible.

Below is relevant code snippet:

```
var hitTest = grid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
int dragRowIndex = hitTest.RowIndex;
if (hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader && dragRowIndex != -1)
{
    //Start dragging
}
```

Comment: I edited the post and removed unnecessary codes which had made reading the question hard and just kept the most important part of code to make the post more useful for future readers. Those who are interested in rest of code posted by the OP, can find the original post in [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38384611/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a hit-test on `DataGridView` using [`HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx) method, the result [`HitTestInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittestinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an internal field named [`typeInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewHitTestInfo.cs) which contains additional information about the hit-test result which you need. The type of the field is an internal enum. You an use [`Reflection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx) to get the internal field value and cast it to an enum containing expected values this way:

```
private enum DataGridViewHitTestTypeInternal
{
    None,
    Cell,
    ColumnHeader,
    RowHeader,
    ColumnResizeLeft,
    ColumnResizeRight,
    RowResizeTop,
    RowResizeBottom,
    FirstColumnHeaderLeft,
    TopLeftHeader,
    TopLeftHeaderResizeLeft,
    TopLeftHeaderResizeRight,
    TopLeftHeaderResizeTop,
    TopLeftHeaderResizeBottom,
    ColumnHeadersResizeBottom,
    ColumnHeadersResizeTop,
    RowHeadersResizeRight,
    RowHeadersResizeLeft,
    ColumnHeaderLeft,
    ColumnHeaderRight
}
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var info = this.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    var typeInternal = info.GetType().GetField("typeInternal", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

    var value = (DataGridViewHitTestTypeInternal)typeInternal.GetValue(info);
    /* Then decide based on value */
    // Rest of logic
    base.OnMouseDown(e);    
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Your answer is perfectly clear (and probably the only solution). I was just hoping to avoid Reflection and not just for speed reasons but mostly because it can break my code (the field may not exist in future versions or the enum may change)

Comment: Don't be worry about that. Surely it wont have performance problem. It's completely OK. Also about changes, I believe it wont change in the future releases, but you can simply add a null checking for the field to check if it found or not :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer as I don't really think there will be any better answer. For the record, even though the speed impact in this case is probably negligible, I did the reflection only once and kept the `FieldInfo` in a `private static` field in the class that uses it. I also added a check for null as suggested.

Comment: A simple reflection in a mouse down will never have an impact on performance. Thanks for the feedback :)